# How to retrieve data from an event review_controller_product_init_before inside the observer in Magento 2?

Tags: event-observer

Using Magento 2, I trying to retrieve the data (rating, nickname, ...) when the user write a review for a product. i want to retrieve this data, do some process and return back to be displayed in the screen.

How to grab this data inside the observer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this  event pass Action as a  parameter of event , Then you can get all field values of the review  form at Observer.

```
$controllerAction =  $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction ();
   $nickname = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParam('nickname', false);
   $title = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParam('title', false);
   $detail = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParam('detail', false);
   $ratings = $controllerAction->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', false)
```